# Unity - Code is fine in the editor, has error on android

Tags: android, unity, javascript

Right. Im running into some weird issue with android unity. I have this bit of code

```
function OnTriggerStay (other : Collider)
{

        if(die.GetComponent(DieScript).sideUp ==6 ||die.GetComponent(DieScript).sideUp ==2 || die.GetComponent(DieScript).sideUp ==4)
    {

       parSys.startSpeed = -5;
        if (other.attachedRigidbody)
        {
        var direction = -(other.attachedRigidbody.transform.position - transform.position*1.5);
            other.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(direction);
        }

        }
```

Now, this runs fine in the unity editor. More then fine, It runs perfectly. However on android the whole OnTriggerStay method fails, and I get this error from logcat

```
I/Unity   (29199): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I/Unity   (29199):   at ZoneScriptDie.OnTriggerStay (UnityEngine.Collider other) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

I/Unity   (29199):  

I/Unity   (29199): (Filename:  Line: -1)

I/Unity   (29199): 

I/Unity   (29199): NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I/Unity   (29199):   at ZoneScriptDie.OnTriggerStay (UnityEngine.Collider other) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

I/Unity   (29199):
```

Why is it failing in android? The whole object freezes up, the particles just hang in place like a frozen snowglobe.

Comment: If you put a lot of debug output in there, you could narrow down the precise line the null reference is occurring on. If I had to guess, it's possible that `die` may be the object that doesn't have a reference.

Comment: Unfortunatly. Thats really all the debug out put I got from Logcat, Its just repeats a bunch of times. 

[link](http://serotoninunderdreams.com/main/paddleBattle.txt)

And in start I have 

`parSys = GetComponent(ParticleSystem);
die = GameObject.Find("die");`

So It should exist. It exists and runs fine in the editor, but not on android. Ill try playing with how it finds the object

Comment: Maybe There would be a better way to log the date? Or would all the non unity debug help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I fixed it, 
I changed the code from

`die = GameObject.find("die"); //Worked fine in the editor`
to
`die = gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject;`

It now runs fine on the phone. So Yes chaosTechnician was right, It wasnt being set. That being said does anyone know why it is that That particular gameObject.find didnt work?

Comment: That's not something we can answer without knowing about that object or how your system manipulates it. Perhaps you were making assumptions about how late it would be destroyed which don't hold true on all platforms.